# close window user input in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm making a batch internet browser, but when I try to make the window close when someone types "close" in, it tries to connect to a website called close. Here is the code so far:

```
@echo off
color 1f
:a
echo -= batch browser-=
echo type close in the website box to close
set /p id="Enter website(that starts with http-://-www.): " %=%
echo loading site......
ping localhost >nul
echo Press any key to open.....
pause >nul
If %id% == "close" goto close
start firefox.exe %id%
echo website open. Press any key to go back to the browser
pause >nul
goto a
:close
exit
```

Can anyone help? If so thanks :)

Comment: Add an `echo %id%` and `pause` before your `if` statement. What exactly is output at that point?

Comment: All it adds is the input I put in (in this case "close") exucutes the pause command, and then tries to open that same "close" website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes are included in the comparison. Your IF statement has quotes on the right, but not on the left. Change it to look like:

```
If "%id%" == "close" goto close
```

You might want to add the `/I` option just in case the user uses upper case.

Also, your code will be safer if it uses delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
color 1f
:a
echo -= batch browser-=
echo type close in the website box to close
set /p id="Enter website(that starts with http-://-www.): " %=%
echo loading site......
ping localhost >nul
echo Press any key to open.....
pause >nul
If /I "!id!" == "close" goto close
start firefox.exe !id!
echo website open. Press any key to go back to the browser
pause >nul
goto a
:close
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Quote `%id%` on your `if` statement

```
If "%id%" == "close" goto close
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to be consistent with quotes on both sides of equal and lose spaces.

```
If %id% == "close" goto close
```

means

```
if close == "close" goto close
```

so

```
if close<space>==<space><quote>close<quote> goto close
```